# array of function pointers with/out typedef and explicit argument declaration

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

I met a peculiar behavior while I was working with function pointer. Let' s suppose I have this code (I'll briefly call it *without typedef*)

```
// without typedef
void* func1(void*);
void* func2(void*);

int main() {
    void* (*func_pntr[])(void*) = {func1, func2};
    return 0;
}

void* func1(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}

void* func2(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}
```

the way this code works, is the usual one, no mystery here. We could also write the typedef equivalent of this code (let's say *typedef1*)

```
// typedef1
typedef void*(*func_t)(void*);

func_t func1(void*);
func_t func2(void*);

int main() {
    func_t (*func_pntr[])(void*) = {func1, func2};
    return 0;
}

func_t func1(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}

func_t func2(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}
```

and also in this case I see no problem in understanding the code. I wrote a third version of the code (call it *typdef2*)

```
// typedef2
typedef void*(*func_t)(void*);

void* func1(void*);
void* func2(void*);

int main() {
    func_t func_pntr[] = {func1, func2};
    return 0;
}

void* func1(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}

void* func2(void* arg) {
    return (void*)0;
}
```

that still WORKS! I wonder about the fact that is possible to omit the argument(s) for the array of function pointers. Again, if I write *typedef2* with `func_t` in place of `void*` for the function declaration/definition the compiler (GCC) is not able to compile.

Does someone has an idea how this happens? To be more precise I compiled with `gcc -std=c89 -Wall test.c` to see if this was something related to a dialect issue.

Comment: Why are you using void pointers?  You are losing lots of type safety here. When I see lots of casts/void pointers I think that the programmer is doing something wrong

Comment: The two top cases are not equivalent. In the first one `func1` (for example) is a function which returns a `void *`. In the second the function returns a pointer to a function. And nowhere do you "omit the argument(s)". In the last case the arguments of the functions for the array are part of the `func_t` type.

Comment: @EdHeal: using void* is not the central issue of the question I posed

Comment: I think you find that this is a fault in the design using void pointers.I left it as a comment

Comment: This is a [useful site C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*func_pntr%5B%5D%29%28void*%29) for issues like this

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude right now I can see the reason why this is possible... and I think this deserve a lot of care to working with, it can be dangerous and the "error" cannot be easily found. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a debugging nightmare. And why do you obfuscate your code and use `(void *)0` for a _null pointer constant_ and not the standard macro `NULL` (which is typically the same)?

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the three examples into one program, renumbering functions, then you can quickly establish that the functions in the second code block in the question return a different type (pointer to function) from the other two code blocks.  For example:

```
// without typedef
void* func1(void*);
void* func2(void*);

extern int arr_func_1(void);
extern int arr_func_2(void);
extern int arr_func_3(void);

int arr_func_1(void) {
    void* (*func_pntr_1[])(void*) = {func1, func2};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        func_pntr_1[i](0);
    return 0;
}

void* func1(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

void* func2(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

// typedef1
typedef void*(*func1_t)(void*);

func1_t func3(void*);
func1_t func4(void*);

int arr_func_2(void) {
    func1_t (*func_pntr_2[])(void*) = {func3, func4};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        func_pntr_2[i](0);
    // func_pntr_2[0] = func1;  // Type mismatch!
    return 0;
}

func1_t func3(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

func1_t func4(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

// typedef2
typedef void*(*func2_t)(void*);

void* func5(void*);
void* func6(void*);

int arr_func_3(void) {
    func2_t func_pntr_3[] = {func5, func6};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        func_pntr_3[i](0);
    // func_pntr_3[0] = func3;  // Type mismatch!
    func_pntr_3[0] = func1;     // OK
    return 0;
}

void* func5(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

void* func6(void* arg) {
    return (void*)((char *)arg + 16);
}

int main(void)
{
    arr_func_1();
    arr_func_2();
    arr_func_3();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly under fairly stringent compilation options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition so-4018-8770.c -o so-4018-8770
```

The loops prevent warnings about unused arguments.

If you uncomment the two lines marked 'Type mismatch!', then you get errors:

```
so-4018-8770.c: In function ‘arr_func_2’:
so-4018-8770.c:34:20: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     func_pntr_2[0] = func2;  // Type mismatch!
                    ^
so-4018-8770.c: In function ‘arr_func_3’:
so-4018-8770.c:56:20: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     func_pntr_3[0] = func4;  // Type mismatch!
                    ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

In the second block of code in the question, the `(void *)` casts in the functions are spurious; the type returned is `void *(*)(void *)`, despite the cast shown — which I preserved in the composite code above.  You could also modify `arr_func_2()` like this:

```
int arr_func_2(void) {
    func1_t (*func_pntr_2[])(void*) = {func3, func4};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        func1_t fp = func_pntr_2[i](0);
        if (fp != 0)
        {
            (*fp)(0);   // Equivalent
            fp(0);      // Equivalent
    }
    // func_pntr_2[0] = func1;  // Type mismatch!
    return 0;
}
```

The two lines marked 'Equivalent' are equivalent to each other — old-style (pre-standard) but explicit notation for invoking a function via function pointer, and new-style.  I still like the old-style because it matches the way you declare function pointers and it saves looking for a function called `fp`.

You couldn't make the parallel changes in the other two functions.

Don't try to run the code fragment above; the functions return a non-null pointer, so the program tries to execute the non-existent function at address 0x00000010, which is not a recipe for happiness.

Answer (score 0):

Some programmer dude's less elaborate, more concise explanation:

> The two top cases are not equivalent. In the first one `func1` (for example) is a function which returns a `void *`. In the second the function returns a pointer to a function. And nowhere do you "omit the argument(s)". In the last case the arguments of the functions for the array are part of the `func_t` type.